# Execução sequencial

Tags: angular, ionic2

Sou novo no mundo do angular e ionic. Tenho uma função principal que executa um comando no banco se esse comando der erro ele chama outra função . Ate ai tudo bem, só que essa função que e chamada não executa da forma correta, pois dentro dela eu chamo uma função que faz um update no banco local, só que essa função só eh executada mesmo quando ele lê todas as linhas dessa função, mesmo eu colocando essa função na primeira linha do meu método, ele só executa no final. Eh como se ignorasse a função e executasse todas as outras linhas e quando todas as outras linhas forem executadas ai sim ele executa minha função. Deu pra entender ? Alguém sabe porque isso acontece? Segue os códigos.

```
 if (this.conectividade.isOnlineCheck()) {
    this.web_service_romaneio.confirmacaoBaixa(body).subscribe(data => {
      if (data == true) {
         //successs
      } else {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    }, erro => {
      erro = true;
    });

  } else {
    //Essa eh a funcao que chamo 
    this.salvarOffLine(this.id_romaneio);
  }
  if (erro) {
    //Essa eh a funcao que chamo 
    this.salvarOffLine(this.id_romaneio);
  } else {

  }

 // Essa eh funcao que chama la em cima e que so executa o update no banco quando acaba a funcao

 salvarOffLine(id) {

   this.loading2 = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Nao foi possivel conectar ao servidor. Salvando dados para uma proxima conexão.'
  });
  this.loading2.present();
 // FUncao que eh ignorada
  this.retornoUpdate = this.bd_local.updateRomaneioConfirmacao(id, 0);
  alert(JSON.stringify(this.retornoUpdate));
  this.loading2.dismiss();
 }
```

E essa eh o código da função que eh "ignorada", que esta dentro de um `provider`.

```
   updateRomaneioConfirmacao(codigo, flag) {
/*
0 - Para identificar que a nota nao foi baixada no webservice pois ocorreu um erro de conexao
1 - Para identificar que a nota foi baixada corretamente
 */
this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'infoged.db',
  location: 'default'
}).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
  db.executeSql("UPDATE tb_romaneio SET romaneio_statusEntrega = 1, romaneio_sincronizada ="+ flag +" where id_romaneio = '" + codigo + "'", [])
    .then(ed => alert(JSON.stringify(ed)))
    .catch(e => alert(JSON.stringify(e)));
}).catch(e => alert(JSON.stringify(e)));

}
```